# Pass env variable from Powershell to a Powershell script inside Docker image

Tags: docker, powershell

I want to pass env variables from my Powershell on Windows to a Powershell script inside my Docker Image.

From my Windows Powershell I defined them like this:

```
$env:MY_VAR = 'test'
$env:MY_VAR2 = 'test2'
```

Then in my Docker image I have this:

```
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# some other stuff...

ADD run.ps1 /

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "/run.ps1"]
```

And my **run.ps1** script is just:

```
gci env:* | sort-object name

echo $env:MY_VAR
echo $env:MY_VAR2
```

I tried something like this:

```
docker run -t my-image:latest -e $env:MY_VAR=$env:MY_VAR -e $env:MY_VAR2=$env:MY_VAR2
```

or:

```
docker run -t my-image:latest -e MY_VAR=$env:MY_VAR -e MY_VAR2=$env:MY_VAR2
```

My env variables are always empty, I don't find the right syntax where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Set your `-e` parameters before the `-t` in your docker command.

**Here is an example:**

On my local powershell:

```
$env:SqlUser
me
```

The docker command:

```
docker run -e SqlUser="$env:SqlUser" -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh
PowerShell 7.2.7
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /> $env:SqlUser
me
PS /> New-Item -Type File test.ps1
PS /> Add-Content ./test.ps1 -Value 'Write-Host "$env:SqlUser"'
PS /> ./test.ps1
me
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, did you try to define a script file inside the docker image, because It doesnt work like this for me

Comment: changed the answer to add a script and print the env var inside the container. Yes worked

Comment: I just found the error, in addition to the answer you gave, it was also the order of the parameters I put : -t the image before the -e values... instead of: -e values and then -t the image. You can edit your answer to solve this :)